# Where should the custom CSS for R Markdown ioslides be stored?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to define custom CSS for the slides produced by R Markdown. In particular, ioslides.

Where should this be stored and how should I reference the path as part of the R Markdown document?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Store the CSS file under the same directory as your Rmd file, and use a relative path. There is an example [in the documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html#custom_css):

```
---
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: styles.css
---
```

BTW, I don't quite recommend you to use ioslides if you care a lot about customizing the styles. See [rstudio/rmarkdown#730](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/730).